# python multiprocessing: write to same excel file

Tags: python, queue, locking, multiprocessing

I am new to Python and I am trying to save the results of five different processes to one excel file (each process write to a different sheet). I have read different posts here, but still can't get it done as I'm very confused about pool.map, queues, and locks, and I'm not sure what is required here to fulfill this task. 
This is my code so far:

```
list_of_days = ["2017.03.20", "2017.03.21", "2017.03.22", "2017.03.23", "2017.03.24"]
results = pd.DataFrame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global list_of_days
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('myfile.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    nr_of_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    l = multiprocessing.Lock()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=nr_of_cores, initializer=init, initargs=(l,))
    pool.map(f, range(len(list_of_days)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def init(l):
    global lock
    lock = l

def f(k):
    global results

    *** DO SOME STUFF HERE***

    results = results[ *** finished pandas dataframe *** ]

    lock.acquire()
    results.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=list_of_days[k])
    writer.save()
    lock.release()
```

The result is that only one sheet gets created in excel (I assume it is the process finishing last). Some questions about this code:

- How to avoid defining global variables?
- Is it even possible to pass around dataframes?
- Should I move the locking to main instead?

Really appreciate some input here, as I consider mastering multiprocessing as instrumental. Thanks

Comment: If you are firing up multiple processes concurrently, you are going to run into file lock issues where each process is trying to access the same file at the same time.  It doesn't matter that they are different sheets, it is still the same file.  Also, the way your code is written, you are overwriting `myfile.xlsx` each time.

Comment: yes, sure, I need to place the locks at the right place such that only 1 process writes down to the file. To your second point: you are right, I removed the writer out of f(k), it's now only in main, this should prevent overwriting the file each time, but nevertheless, the output only contains one sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Why did you implement time.sleep in several places in your 2nd method?

In `__main__`, `time.sleep(0.1)`, to give the started `process` a timeslice to startup.
   In `f2(fq, q)`, to give the `queue` a timeslice to flushed all buffered data to the pipe and
   as `q.get_nowait()` are used.
   In `w(q)`, are only for testing simulating long run of `writer.to_excel(...)`,
   i removed this one.

> 2) What is the difference between pool.map and pool = [mp.Process( . )]?

Using `pool.map` needs no `Queue`, no parameter passed, shorter code. 
    The `worker_process` have to return immediately the `result` and terminates.
    `pool.map` starts a new process as long as all `iteration` are done.
The `results` have to be processed after that.

Using `pool = [mp.Process( . )]`,  starts **n** `processes`.
 A `process` terminates on `queue.Empty`

> Can you think of a situation where you would prefer one method over the other?

Methode 1: Quick setup, serialized, only interested in the result to continue.
    Methode 2: If you want to do all workload **parallel**.

---

You **could't** use `global writer` in processes.
The `writer` instance has to belong to one `process`.

Usage of  `mp.Pool`, for instance:

```
def f1(k):
  # *** DO SOME STUFF HERE***
  results = pd.DataFrame(df_)
  return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool()
    results = pool.map(f1, range(len(list_of_days)))

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('../test/myfile.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    for k, result in enumerate(results):
        result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=list_of_days[k])

    writer.save()
    pool.close()
```

This leads to `.to_excel(...)` are called in sequence in the `__main__` process.

---

If you want parallel `.to_excel(...)` you have to use `mp.Queue()`.
For instance:

The `worker` process:

```
# mp.Queue exeptions have to load from
try:
    # Python3
    import queue
except:
    # Python 2
    import Queue as queue

def f2(fq, q):
    while True:
        try:
            k = fq.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            exit(0)

        # *** DO SOME STUFF HERE***

        results = pd.DataFrame(df_)
        q.put( (list_of_days[k], results) )
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

The `writer` process:

```
def w(q):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('myfile.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    while True:
        try:
            titel, result = q.get()
        except ValueError:
            writer.save()
            exit(0)

        result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=titel)
```

The `__main__` process:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    w_q = mp.Queue()
    w_p = mp.Process(target=w, args=(w_q,))
    w_p.start()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    f_q = mp.Queue()
    for i in range(len(list_of_days)):
        f_q.put(i)

    pool = [mp.Process(target=f2, args=(f_q, w_q,)) for p in range(os.cpu_count())]
    for p in pool:
        p.start()
        time.sleep(0.1)

    for p in pool:
        p.join()

    w_q.put('STOP')
    w_p.join()
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - pandas:0.19.2 - xlsxwriter:0.9.6***

Comment: Thanks @stovfl! Both of your methods work fine. Interesting to see how one can avoid locks here by using Queues.
Questions: 1) Why did you implement time.sleep in several places in your 2nd method?
2) What is the difference between pool.map and pool = [mp.Process( . )]? Can you think of a situation where you would prefer one method over the other?

Comment: @SuperMartingale: Updated Answer. Please report back: How many `processes`, how big is your **saved time** without `multiprocessing`. Update your Question with this info.