# interleaved output on shared file write

Tags: python

I have a long running python program doing "append" write (multi-process) on a shared file:

```
out = open("shared_file", "a")
while has_input:
     do_processing()
     out.write("%s, %s, %s\n" % field1, field2, field3)
```

The above pseudo code are run with 8 processes, say. This will result in a small portion of interleaving output. This seems buffer-related based on google search. What's the proper way of doing shared file append?

Comment: Try implementing a file lock system. There are a few packages like `FileLock` and the unix util `flock`

Comment: No need for an external package -- the Python standard library has `flock()` support.

Comment: That said, you might just consider disabling buffering for your file. Kernel-level semantics will generally stop any individual `O_APPEND` from being non-atomic, as long as the writes aren't so long that they need to be split into two or more calls. `out = open("shared_file", "a", 0)`

Comment: Backing up, re: "interleaving output" -- is your concern cases where you have a single line that contains content from two different processes, or cases where you have output that alternates between multiple processes?

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: What's the proper way of doing shared file append?

1. Use **one** writer [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process), only to write/append data to the file.
2. Share the workload with the other processes.
3. Use a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) to pass the data to append from the workload processes to the writer process.

Read this SO Answer: [python-multiprocessing-write-to-same-excel-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092144/python-multiprocessing-write-to-same-excel-file/43101031#43101031)

Comment: Definitely the right thing with a more complex file format like XLS, but not as necessary for append-only content.

Comment: If your _"file format"_ allow concurrent read/write, use also **one** reader `process`.

Comment: Why? You can have as many separate processes reading a file at the same time without having any impact on each other at all. If your goal is to avoid having any reader try to consume file with partial or incomplete writes, the answer is not to avoid concurrent readers, but to take out a *shared* read lock (which multiple readers can hold at once, but which prevents any *exclusive* write lock from being held until all such readers have exited).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: It's only a conceptual proposal, feel free to do it with `locking`. Take in account, File IO with locking can lead to performance breakdown. The overall performance depends on the balance between in Memory workload and File IO workload.

Comment: (Aside: Putting `process` and `locking` in backticks implies that they're code -- ie. that there's a Python module, keyword, function, etc., by that name, as opposed to just being human-language technical terms).

Comment: ...back to point, though: If this were appropriately tuned ("appropriately tuned", in this case, meaning doing a whole batch of writes without releasing and re-grabbing the lock within the batch, if and only if all the items in that batch are immediately ready), I'd be very surprised if the impact were much greater than operating through FIFOs as used for multiprocessing. There are costs in both places.

Comment: See [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text) on [meta].

Answer (score 1):

The [`fcntl` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html) has helpers that are relevant here. If you want to keep an entire block of writes (`while has_input:`) together, you might do so with the following:

```
with out = open("shared_file", "a"):
    fcntl.flock(out, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
    try:
        while has_input:
            out.write("%s, %s, %s\n" % (field1, field2, field3))
    finally:
        fcntl.flock(out, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
```

By contrast, if you only care about keeping individual lines together, and don't mind a bit of additional overhead, one can use finer-grained locking:

```
with out = open("shared_file", "a"):
    while has_input:
        try:
            fcntl.flock(out, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
            out.write("%s, %s, %s\n" % (field1, field2, field3))
        finally:
            fcntl.flock(out, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
```

---

That said, if your goal is just to prevent a single line from having content from two different processes, and have opened your file with `O_APPEND`, operating-system-level semantics are generally fairly effective at keeping individual writes atomic. One way that atomicity can be *broken* is buffering, but you can avoid the effect by opening your file without a buffer, so that all writes are immediately flushed:

```
out = open("shared_file", "a", 0)
```