# python multiprocessing to create an excel file with multiple sheets

Tags: python, dataframe, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocessing to export the results (multiple pandas dataframes) of a function to multiple sheets in the same excel file. In order to do this, I've come up with the following.

test_multiprocessing_3.py

```
def aggregator(d):
    df = d[0]
    writer = d[1]
    col1 = d[2]
    col2 = d[3]
    agg_df = df.groupby([col1, col2]).apply(lambda x: 100 * (x['enr'].sum() / len(x))).reset_index(name='ontime_en_rate')
    sheet_name = str(col1 + "_" + col2 + "_ontime_en")
    agg_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, index=False)
```

test_multiprocessing_4.py

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import pandas as pd
import test_multiprocessing_3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    writer = ExcelWriter('D:/Exports/user_funct_agg_test9.xlsx')
    df_main = pd.read_excel('D:/Exports/test_data.xlsx')
    dimensions = [(df_main, writer,'member', 'type'), (df_main, writer,'member', 'month')]
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        pool.map(test_multiprocessing_3.aggregator, dimensions)
    writer.save()
```

But I'm getting the following error:
`TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'`

Also, I'm running Python v3.7.5 on Windows 10 machine. I have also tried to keep the function and call in the same file but I get the same error.

test_multiprocessing_5.py

```
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from pandas import ExcelWriter


def aggregator(data_chunks):
    df = data_chunks[0]
    file_name = data_chunks[1]
    col1 = data_chunks[2]
    col2 = data_chunks[3]
    agg_df = df.groupby([col1,col2]).apply(lambda x: 100*(x['enr'].sum()/len(x))).reset_index(name='ontime_en_rate')
    sheet_name = str(col1 + "_" + col2 + "_ontime_en")
    agg_df.to_excel(file_name, sheet_name, index=False)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    writer = ExcelWriter('D:/Exports/user_funct_agg_test9.xlsx')
    df_main = pd.read_excel('D:/Exports/test_data.xlsx')
    dimensions = [(df_main, writer,'member', 'type'), (df_main, writer,'member', 'month')]
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        pool.map(aggregator, dimensions)
    writer.save()
```

Any help as to which step did I make a mistake?

Edit: Thanks to @stovfl for the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43101031/7414759

Updated Working Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp
from pandas import ExcelWriter



def aggregator(df, col1, col2):
    agg_df = df.groupby([col1, col2]).apply(lambda x: 100 * (x['enr'].sum() / len(x))).reset_index(name='ontime_en_rate')
    return agg_df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=3)
    df_main = pd.read_excel('D:/Exports/test_data.xlsx')
    dimensions = [(df_main, 'member', 'type'), (df_main, 'member', 'month')]
    results = pool.starmap(aggregator, dimensions)
    writer = ExcelWriter('D:/Exports/user_funct_agg_test9.xlsx')
    for k, result in enumerate(results):
        sheet_name = 'ontime_'+str(k)
        result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name,index=False)
    writer.save()
    pool.close()
```

Comment: at which line are you getting this error?

Comment: hello @DDhaliwal - The exact line number from the code is not mentioned. `Process SpawnPoolWorker-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\sravee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'`

Comment: thank you @stovfl -- your first method worked! Will try your second method as well :)